# how to get Text Messages list from iphone in monotouch

Tags: iphone, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Hi im working on iphone application using monotouch im trying to get list of all the text messages stored in iphone (inbox), for getting contact information there is ABAddressBook class but i not found any class like that for text messages can any one help me in this regards how can i get the list of text messages .thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the text messages from the messages app in the iPhone. Apple does not allow this.

Comment: is there is no way to get messages? i want to take backup of all messages on ftpserver.

Comment: No there is no way, a iTunes sync will already backup the messages.